# S3 Dependency not packaging

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3, package, dependencies

When I run my program in the AWS lambda, I am getting the error

```
com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream
    at dvsa.mib.components.DaggerUploadFileStreamComponent.buildUploadFileStreamService(DaggerUploadFile    StreamComponent.java:39)
    at dvsa.mib.LambdaHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHandler.java:27)
    at dvsa.mib.LambdaHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHandler.java:14)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

I have used maven to package the project, created in intellij, using mvn clean package. The pom contains the dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.623</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

with extension

```
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```

amongst its code. I have read in other questions that it is possibly due to a missing dependency but as I have included the ones above I'm not sure what is absent. Any help will be gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: can you create a bare minimum repo and share the URL here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to invoke Amazon S3 operations from within an AWS Lambda function. There is a multi service example that invokes these services from a Lambda function created by using the Lambda Java runtime API:

- Amazon S3 service
- Amazon Rekognition service
- Amazon DynamoDB service
- Amazon Simple Email service

The use case is the AWS Lambda function is able to detect personal protective equipment (PPE) in images located in an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket. It shows you how to build the Lambda function, package it, and deploy it.

See [Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe).